# How to produce an initial at the first line of a paragraph without enlargin the line-height?

Tags: xslt, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I want an initial at the first line of a paragraph and a text-indent for all the other paragraphs. I'm using the following code:

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- no text-indent, first letter bigger -->
        <xsl:when test="fn:position() = 1">
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" font-height="12pt">
                <fo:inline font-size="18pt"><xsl:value-of 
                  select="substring(.,1,1)"/></fo:inline>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2)"/>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- text-indent --> 
            <fo:block line-height="12pt"  
                text-indent="10pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This works, but the line-height of the first line is enlarged and there is to much space between the lines. [image]

line-height-attributes or `<fo:initial-property-set>` don't work. 
Thanks a lot.

Edit: I'm using fop

Edit: FOP doesn't support `<fo:float>` or `<fo:initial-property-set>`. I tried another code using `<fo:list>`:

```
        <xsl:when test="fn:position() = 1">
            <fo:block font-family="Times" font-size="10pt" line-height="12pt"> 
                <fo:list-block>
                    <fo:list-item>
                        <fo:list-item-label>
                            <fo:block font-size="18pt"><xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,1)"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:list-item-label>
                        <fo:list-item-body>
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2)"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:list-item-body>
                    </fo:list-item>
                </fo:list-block>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

So i used figure space `&#8199;` in the value-of select pattern of the `<fo:list-item-body>`:

```
        <xsl:when test="fn:position() = 1">
            <fo:block font-family="Times" font-size="10pt" line-height="12pt"> 
                <fo:list-block>
                    <fo:list-item>
                        <fo:list-item-label>
                            <fo:block font-size="18pt"><xsl:value-of select="substring(.,1,1)"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:list-item-label>
                        <fo:list-item-body>
                            <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="('&#8199;', '&#8199;', substring(.,2))"/></fo:block>
                        </fo:list-item-body>
                    </fo:list-item>
                </fo:list-block>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
```

This isn't just dowdy, it also doesn't work really good:

[image]

[image]

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: The correct name for this is  "drop cap". Googling that, I found http://www.renderx.com/usecasestest.html -- does this work?

Comment: FOP doesn't allow you to use floats

Comment: I have no idea what FOP does or doesn;t support, but if your only complaint is the line-height used in the paragraph and you want the first letter to be enlarged (not drop cap), then set the line-height fixed or set the line-stacking-strategy to line-height. If FOP does not support float, you will not be able to create a drop cap that impacts the indent of more than the first line.

Comment: Well I tested with FOP, it does not support proper line stacking so you cannot do either the enlarged first letter or drop cap (because of no support for float). I also tested with RenderX and either works as expected. Like this: <fo:block line-stacking-strategy="line-height" line-height="10pt"><fo:inline font-size="20pt">I</fo:inline> have no idea...

Comment: As Kevin, I have no idea what FOP does and does not. Can you, for instance, indent the second line in a paragraph but not the first line?

Comment: Here you can find a overview of all the fop features: http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/compliance.html

Comment: So given those FOP features, the issue you have is apparent. FO does not support a line-stacking-strategy of "line-height" which is what you require in order to ensure the separation of the first line is not larger than the remaining ones. I would assume then the line-height of the first line is being set by the max-font-height (which of course is larger for your first letter).

Answer (score 3):

This xsl snippet, minimally revised from the first one in the question, produces the desired result using Apache FOP:

```
<xsl:template match="paragraph">
    <xsl:choose>
        <!-- no text-indent, first letter bigger -->
        <xsl:when test="not(preceding-sibling::paragraph)">
            <fo:block line-height="12pt" 
                line-stacking-strategy="font-height">
                <fo:inline font-size="18pt"><xsl:value-of 
                  select="substring(.,1,1)"/></fo:inline>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2)"/>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- text-indent --> 
            <fo:block line-height="12pt"  
                text-indent="10pt">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/></fo:block>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Important points:

- all fo:blocks are given the same **line-height**
- the first one has **line-stacking-strategy="font-height"**, so the formatter builds the lines using the [nominal-requested-line-rectangle](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#area-line), regardless of the dimensions of inline children
- testing the condition **position() = 1**, as done in the question, is a bit risky if the input file is indented (as child #1 could be a text node made only of whitespace, and the "first" *paragraph* element would be child #2), so I check **not(preceding-sibling::paragraph)** instead
- the initial letter of the first paragraph overflows the resulting line area; some **space-before** can be set on the fo:block to avoid this, if needed